# How to clone complete database in influxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am creating back up of measurement with in Db as shown below:

```
SELECT * INTO backdata FROM sourcedata
```

Above command created backdata measurement. Is there a way to clone complete DB with all measurement with different dbname?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you'll need to create a new database

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
```

Then the following query should work

```
SELECT * INTO mydb..:MEASUREMENT FROM /.*/ GROUP BY *
```

Comment: Thanks it works . SELECT * INTO mydb..:MEASUREMENT from  sourcemeasurement